# failed to build valid URL when spaces are contained within

Tags: java, url, spaces

I ran into a very strange error in Java. It regards building URLs when they have spaces contained. For instance, this link:
[camping at clark](http://www.sas.usace.army.mil/lakes/thurmond/images/camping%20at%20clark%202.jpg)

and this sample snippet of code, which reproduces the error:

`String urlEncoded2 = "http%3A//www.sas.usace.army.mil/lakes/thurmond/images/camping+at+clark+2.jpg";`

```
BufferedImage test = ImageIO.read(new URL(URLDecoder.decode(urlEncoded2, "UTF-8")));`
```

As you can see the url string passed, is UTF-8 encoded. However, no matter how I pass it, this code always fails. In my application I need to be able to read **any image URL passed** with no exclusions.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"http%3A//www.sas.usace.army.mil/lakes/thurmond/images/camping+at+clark+2.jpg"
```

This is not a valid URL.

```
"http://www.sas.usace.army.mil/lakes/thurmond/images/camping at clark 2.jpg"
```

This is not a valid URL.

The problem is that the first value is just junk. Whatever encoded that value didn't do it correctly and this should be fixed at source.

The correct URL is:

```
"http://www.sas.usace.army.mil/lakes/thurmond/images/camping%20at%20clark%202.jpg"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, it's the JS' escape function, which converted it like that, i.e. the first URL.